# jquery function keeps repeating by one on button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am very new to jquery and I have been debugging this code through chrome's debugging tool. Every time I click the button, the function works, but if I click it again the function executes twice, and if I click it again it executes 3 times. I'm not sure why this could be happening. Code is below. It might have to do with the fact that the project is webforms and there are update panels within it?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#BlueButton").click(function () {
        $(this).click(function () {
            alert('Hello');
        }); 
    });
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It will happen like that. since you coded in that way. Remove the event binding inside of the main(`"#BlueButton"`) click event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#BlueButton").click(function () {
            alert('Hello');
    });
});
```

Event will be fired in order as much times you bound it. So do not bind duplicate events.

Comment: I should have mentioned that i have mutlitple buttons generated dynamically with the same ID. The problem is still occuring, so im not sure if this could be causing it?

Comment: @Monzingo You can't have different buttons with same ID. That is the rule. set those elements a common class and use it for event binding.

Comment: ok i have edited it so that they have a common class, so i have 3 buttons with a common class, yet the problem is still occuring.

Comment: @Monzingo You have to bind event like  `$(".commonClass").click(function () {
            alert('Hello');
    });`

Comment: yes, this is how i bound it. I still dont understand why this is occuring. Could it have something to do with update panel in an asp.net page?

Comment: @Monzingo Can you reproduce it in jsfiddle.net ?